# How to set up a Docker image as a reverse proxy with HTTPS for a locally started Spring Boot application?

Tags: docker, https

I am looking for a standardized and straightforward way to set up a Docker image as a reverse proxy with HTTPS for a Spring Boot application that's started locally on my machine.

I initially expected that this could be handled with Nginx and something like Let's Encrypt, but I haven't found a reliable solution yet.

Ideally, I'd like it to be just a Dockerfile and a reference in docker-compose.yml. I would also prefer the certificates, similar to those from Let's Encrypt, to be generated using the CMD command in the Dockerfile.

This setup will be used solely for local development. However, I do not want the certificates to be self-signed.

I have the following line added to /etc/hosts:

127.0.0.1 dasma.local

The dasma.local should proxy to http://host.docker.internal:10043 (this could also be some other localhost).

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to set up Nginx as a reverse proxy within a Docker container, using Let's Encrypt for SSL/TLS certificates. I followed these steps:

I started by creating a Dockerfile and an Nginx configuration file.
In the Dockerfile, I installed Nginx and Certbot, and I set up the Nginx configuration to proxy requests to my local Spring Boot application.
I used Certbot to generate SSL/TLS certificates in the Dockerfile's CMD command.
I added the necessary line to my /etc/hosts file to map dasma.local to my local machine.
However, when I tried to access my application via https://dasma.local, I encountered several issues. First, I received errors saying "Unable to register an account with ACME server" and "host not found in upstream". Then, when trying to access the page, I got a "PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR".

I expected that the setup would allow me to access my local Spring Boot application over HTTPS using the domain dasma.local, with a valid SSL/TLS certificate generated by Let's Encrypt.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly set up this kind of development environment.